# Btrfs input/output error

Tags: ssd, btrfs, nvme

I have a weird issue with a broken kernel image that broke when uninstalling. It looks like an hard drive error - however I am not 100% sure.

I could maybe ignore this but as this is related to an installed linux image I can no longer remove this image. Running `apt upgrade` now returns:

```
Fetched 54,0 MB in 9s (5.581 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                        
(Reading database ... 652815 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.14.13-041413-generic (4.14.13-041413.201801101001) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.14.13-041413-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/4.14.13-041413-generic/kernel/fs/ntfs/ntfs.ko.dpkg-tmp': Input/output error
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.14.13-041413-generic
```

And simply abort the upgrade. I could not get apt to stop trying to remove this package with any advice giving in this community. There are always input/output errors popping up. 
I tried to run smartmontools on the SSD (it is an nvme device) but it simply returns nothing. It doesn't even really recognize the device (unknown model) even though I am using a recent version of smartmontools.
Any advice would be highly appreciated - I will probably soon send the SSD to the seller as I cannot work with a broken state like this.

dmesg:

```
[ 7505.464153] BTRFS error (device dm-0): bdev /dev/dm-0 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 4
[ 7505.464156] BTRFS error (device dm-0): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 49416634368 on dev /dev/dm-0
[ 7505.464159] BTRFS error (device dm-0): bdev /dev/dm-0 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 5
[ 7505.464160] BTRFS error (device dm-0): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 49416552448 on dev /dev/dm-0
[ 7505.465547] BTRFS warning (device dm-0): checksum/header error at logical 49416962048 on dev /dev/dm-0, sector 44088704: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 257
[ 7505.465549] BTRFS warning (device dm-0): checksum/header error at logical 49416962048 on dev /dev/dm-0, sector 44088704: metadata leaf (level 0) in tree 257
[ 7505.465551] BTRFS error (device dm-0): bdev /dev/dm-0 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 6
[ 7505.465554] BTRFS error (device dm-0): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 49416962048 on dev /dev/dm-0
[ 7611.150366] BTRFS error (device dm-0): parent transid verify failed on 49416634368 wanted 192617 found 340661
[ 7611.150569] BTRFS error (device dm-0): parent transid verify failed on 49416634368 wanted 192617 found 340661
[ 7616.836634] BTRFS error (device dm-0): parent transid verify failed on 49416634368 wanted 192617 found 340661
[ 7616.836837] BTRFS error (device dm-0): parent transid verify failed on 49416634368 wanted 192617 found 340661
```

btrfs scrub:

```
scrub status for 59deeb9a-a07e-4aaa-91d6-dd5a12d7959c
    scrub started at Wed Feb 14 08:50:48 2018 and finished after 00:00:08
    total bytes scrubbed: 22.60GiB with 3 errors
    error details: verify=3
    corrected errors: 0, uncorrectable errors: 3, unverified errors: 0
```